# How to convert a label into hyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone have an idea of how to convert a label in ASP.net into a hyperlink.

Comment: I don't even have an idea of what exactly you mean.

Comment: Well you can do `label1.Controls.Add(pass you hyperlink control)`

Comment: You can also use label1.Text = `String.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", "your_url", "your_link_text_here")`

Comment: Thanks Vamsi!! It worked just d way i wanted it to!! Alwaz depending on tool box is not necessary!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an email label a hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046317/making-an-email-label-a-hyperlink)

Answer (score 5):

You can't convert, as such.

You need to use the [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control instead of the [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) control.

A Label doesn't have a `NavigateUrl` property or any equivalent. A HyperLink resolves to an `a` tag. An `a` tag without a `href` attribute (`NavigateUrl` property) may aswell just be a Label.

However, if you change your ASP.NET code to use the `asp:HyperLink` tag rather than the `asp:Label` tag, you can then add a `NavigateUrl` property and keep the rest of the code in tact.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this.**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='Google' />
</a>
```