# Making an email label a hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, label

I was wondering if it is possible to make a label a hyperlink?  Below is the code for a column I have set up and I want to make "lblEmail" clickable so that the email opens up and with that email address in it.  The idea is that as various users log in to the site, their unique info will appear in the column.  Is it as simple as wrapping the label control in an anchor tag?  If so, I must be missing something because I tried that.  Since I am new, it is likely I missed something!

Thanks in advance!

```
<p>
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPhoneNo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>, <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblZipCode" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a label, you could make use of an hyperlink control.
The usage is as follows:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
              ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
              NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com"
              Text="Microsoft Official Site"
              Target="_new"
              runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a hyperlink server control?

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" id="lnk1">Your Text Here</asp:Hyperlink>
```

If you need additional formatting, you can wrap it in other another tag (or insert any legal HTML tag within the hyperlink).

Comment: I suppose that would make more sense!  I inherited this site from some one else and tried to leave their code the way it was, lol.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ***using a label like hyperlink way***, you should better use directly a hyperlink. Try the following :

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" id="email" NavigateUrl="your_desired_address">
    EmailLabelContent here
</asp:Hyperlink>
```

Thanks.